# Can I load rows from an excel sheet to a database table in BULK

Tags: oracle11g, oracle11gr2, oracle11gr1

I have to `INSERT` 500 rows to a table in Oracle 11g. I am using the below command one-by-one.Can I do it all at a time?

for e.g. what I am doing now-

```
INSERT INTO bonus SELECT ename, job, sal, comm FROM emp
   WHERE comm > sal * 0.25;
...
INSERT INTO emp (empno, ename, job, sal, comm, deptno)
   VALUES (4160, 'STURDEVIN', 'SECURITY GUARD', 2045, NULL, 30);
...
INSERT INTO dept
   VALUES (my_deptno, UPPER(my_dname), 'CHICAGO');
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would export my Excel table in CSV format, and use search and replace, using regular expressions, in an editor to substitute each line of comma separated values for an INSERT command, and then run those commands.

Comment: can we do the same with any other oracle script or any so?

Comment: Yes. And if you provide an example of your CSV exported data I can provide the regular expression I'd use.

Answer (score 1):

Download SQL Developer. It has a nice function to insert into a table from an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: I am looking for any oracle script which can perform this by itself if we form any command script so.

Comment: Arup, I suggest you take a look at the command line utility SQL*Loader, if you are not already familiar with it. While it can't insert directly from Excel, it can bulk load CSV and other text data files. See [this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ) and [this](http://psoug.org/reference/sqlloader.html) site for a good survey of its capabilities and operation. I've used both SQL*Loader and SQL Developer to load CSV files from Excel into 11g, and prefer the former for large imports.

Answer (score 1):

Look into **SQLLoader**.

This sentence left intentionally blank.

Comment: I am not educated in SQL Loader,so if you help me here with that,then i would be more happy to learn from you!

Comment: There is sufficient information online to get your head wrapped around it.  The problem is left as an exercise for the student.